# java.io.IOException: Authorization loop detected on Conduit in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:416)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:218)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:99)

Camel version - 2.16.1.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Authorization loop detected on Conduit "webserviceURL here..."

trying to call a WS published, from "route id=1" which is available in "routeContext id=1", from "route id=2" which is defined in "routeContext id=2"..
WS - defined using CXF-endpoint..
Both the "routeContext" has "http:conduit" defined..
Tried removing one of it..Not successful..

Comment: May I know the reason for down voting...!!

Comment: how do your routes look like? What have you defined in your http:conduit ?

Comment: mentioned in the question @Ramin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is,

you have to be more specific of the scope of http:conduit, can be acheived by providing the specific name to the configured conduit, eg: http:conduit name="abcd.http", will be available only to the 'abcd', here abcd~=Webservice